# Can't see russian subtitles the right way in Kodi

Tags: windows-7, kodi

I use Kodi on Windows 7, to see movies. I would like to see subtitles in Russian but I see them in gibberish (Hebrew characters). How do I set Kodi for my PC, to be able to display the Russian subtitles the right way?